# The network connection was lost. Xcode 5 Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-yosemite

Whenever I try to submit my update to the iOS app store I get an error stating

`The network connection was lost.`

I tried to submit from the Xcode 6 Beta but I get an error that basically says I cannot submit from Xcode 6 yet.

Does anyone know how I can fix the `The network connection was lost.`?

I've restarted the iOS device and my MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Yosemite right now has some bugs that we must report to Apple in order to get solved. For example I cannot drag and drop any element to .h or .m files anymore, it will crash if I do so. I would suggest you to open the console from your 'Other' folder, and try to locate where the problem is happening. Then you will get a better chance of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I have also problems connecting my WiFi network at home. My work around is to use my phone and USB-cable to connect to the internet. Not nice to have but it works here. I have to mention that I use an old MacBook Pro.